# 「配列から最大値を消すプログラムを作りたい」を、pythonを使って1行で書く事ができますか

Tags: python

(参考)
[配列から最大値を消すプログラムを作りたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/72770/%e9%85%8d%e5%88%97%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e6%9c%80%e5%a4%a7%e5%80%a4%e3%82%92%e6%b6%88%e3%81%99%e3%83%97%e3%83%ad%e3%82%b0%e3%83%a9%e3%83%a0%e3%82%92%e4%bd%9c%e3%82%8a%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84)

以下pythonプログラムをSymPy Liveで実行しました。
https://live.sympy.org/

```
# 全ての最大値10を削除します。
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
myMax=max(list)
while myMax in list :
    list.remove(myMax)
print(list)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: `lst.remove(max(lst))`

Comment: list を変数名に使用するのは止めましょう。（組み込み関数のため）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[x for x in xs if x != max(xs)]
```

Comment: ポイントとなる部分の (簡単な) 解説も含めてあると、より良い回答になるかもしれません。

Comment: えっ、コードが全てを語ってませんかこれ